# query for selecting count(*) and columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I have this query which fetches rows from a table and the number of rows that the query is gonna return:

```
SELECT tab.*, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   mytable mtb 
        WHERE  mtb.name = 'XYZ' 
               AND mtb.TYPE = 'TP') 
FROM   mytable tab 
WHERE  tab.name = 'XYZ' 
       AND tab.TYPE = 'TP'
```

Now if you see the I simply want the number of rows that the main query returns with all the other columns. I need to use this query as a subquery in a very large query. Now i want to know if there is a better way to write this query. I mean we are repeating the query just to get the count separately. So can you please provide a more optimized form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the analytic function `count()`:

```
select tab.*, count(*) over () as totalcnt
from mytable tab
where tab.name = 'XYZ' and tab.type = 'TP'
```

Comment: Isn't COUNT( * ) OVER () the same as plain COUNT( * )?

Comment: @kyooryu: no it's not. A "plain" count with additional columns would require a `GROUP BY` on those columns.

Comment: actually, after some testing I found that what I really needed was `count(*) over(partition by name,type)`! Thanks a lot for helping me learn new commands :)